# Need advice on how to store a stopwatch for each array item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, timer

Currently working on a react project that handles calls. At the moment, I have both a reducer and a context to store and perform actions on the calls, with 2 different arrays, one for paused calls, other for ringing calls and an object for the current call in conversation.

I want to display a stopwatch / timer for each call to show the user how long he has been in said call, however I am having trouble deciding what the best approach for storing the timer would be. At the moment, Im attempting the following :

```
const [conversationCall, setConversationCall] = useState<CurrentCallObject | null>({
  callState : "Calling",
  callDetails : {
     timer : 0,
     timerFunc : setInterval(() => 
     {
        
     }, 10),
     standby : true,
     event_type: "call_started",
     event_time: Date.now().toString(),
     call_id: "12",
     remote_number: "919999999",
     event_parameter: ""
  }})
```

What I was trying to do here was set an Interval has a property for each object so that it would be deleted with the object, however im having problems updating the timer value inside the timerFunc setInterval.
I also tried using hooks for starting timers, but I had trouble with it because I change the state inside functions and I cant use hooks inside functions, so kinda stuck here at the moment.
Any help is appreciated